# How to make game scene bigger in 2d platformer?

Tags: unity, 2d, platformer

Hi i am current making a 2D platformer game but after i reach an end of screen then it doesn't move forward how to increase the game play screen area so that i will be able to go in vertical direction i am pasting an image of the problem i am new to unity please help me![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5vnl.png)

Comment: Do your want to make your camera bigger so more fits into the frame at a time? (Each individual item will become smaller) Or do you want to implement a camera follow or room transition behaviour so the view moves when you get to the edges / particular transition zones?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer of the question 
increase xMax and YMax to increase the game screen so that camera will follow you

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float xMax;
    [SerializeField]
    private float yMax;
    [SerializeField]
    private float xMin;
    [SerializeField]
    private float yMin;
    // Use this for initialization

    private Transform target;
    void Start()
    {
        target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(target.position.x, xMin, xMax), Mathf.Clamp(target.position.y, yMin, yMax), transform.position.z);
    }
}
```